# JSON JOLT transformation - list of list to list of nth elements

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to write a JOLT transformation for the input:

```
{
  "time": 1581512850,
  "states": [
    [
      "dewf",
      "deswd",
      -79.1016,
      35.5882
    ],
    [
      "dedaswf",
      "desfdaeswwd",
      -79.5016,
      135.8882
    ]
  ]
}
```

The expected JSON is:

```
{
  "time": 1581512850,
  "states": [
    {
      "longitude": -79.1016,
      "latitude": 35.5882
    },
    {
      "longitude": -79.5016,
      "latitude": 65.8882
    }
  ]
}
```

But I cannot get any closer to the solution. Could you please advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "time": "time",
      "states": {
        "*": {
          "2": "states.[&1].longitude",
          "3": "states.[&1].latitude"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```